# Laravel: Eloquent Relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, relationship

I have three tables "users", "roles" and "role_users". Apparently, user table does not have any role_id field. Therefore mapping of user with role is maintained in "role_users" table by having role_id and user_id fields.

What association i will need to write in both models User and Role to fetch a list of all users of a particular role e.g.'teacher'?

Here is what i am currently doing in User model:

```
public function teachers() {
    return $this->has_many('Role')->where('name','teacher');
}
```

This is not working, but i could not understand that how would i make the relationship in this model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Laravel docs - many to many relation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#many-to-many)

```
public function teachers() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Role')->where('name','teacher');
}
```

Comment: Ok, but when i call this method in the controller like  $users = User::with('teachers'); echo "<pre>"; print_r($users); exit; then page kept loading and no result is displayed. It seems like some infinite loop is going on.Also do i need to write anything in Role model? Please suggest

Comment: That's probably because the output of `print_r` in this case is very very big ... For debugging, try `$users->toJson()` or `$users->toArray()` instead

Comment: Does toArray() is an inbuilt function of eloquent?

Comment: Can you please send chat invite to discuss in detail?

Comment: Yes it is. [Source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L2253-L2258). Sorry I can't chat at the moment. Maybe later...

Comment: I just saw that this solution pulling those users as well whose role is not teacher... Any idea?

Comment: You probably want to do something like this: `User::has('teachers')->get()`. This will only fetch users that have the `teacher` role.